# Javascript. Transform synchronous function as asynchronous using callbacks, promises, async/await, generators

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, synchronization

I have two functions, witch previously were designed to run synchronously.

```
function addOne(recievedInt) {
   ...some network requests happend...
   return recievedInt = receivedInt++;
}
```

and

```
function sum(arg1, arg2) {
   ... do some manipulations...
   return arg1 + arg2;
}
```

Latter both were changed to be asynchronous using callbacks and look as following: function

```
addOne(recievedInt, callback),  sum(arg1, arg2, callback)
```

Now I need to change third functions which previously was using both functions from synchronous to async passing callback to each of them.

```
function compute(value) {
   var c = addOne(value);
   var a = sum(value, c) + c;
   return a;
}
```

My best solutions was:

```
function compute(value) {
   return addOne(value, function(n1) {
      return sum(value, n1, function(n2) {
         return n2 + n1;
      });
   });
}
```

Is that is the right implementation for callback based asynchronous version? And how it can be converted using async/await, generators, Promises

Comment: I think the real question is **why** do these needs to become asynchronous? Do these perform **async** operations? or is it just matter of handling a **callback**?

Comment: not sure if this is fully a dupe, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) might have some ideas that help you

Comment: briosheje, yes, they perform sync operations, I just didn't paste that bit.

Comment: do they perform SYNC or **A**SYNC operations? if they perform **sync** operations, may I ask you why you need to make them **async**? Of course you can do that by simply wrapping them in promise blocks, but the question, to me, is **why** you should do that, since they are **not** async.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could refactor your original code to async/await (without using callbacks):

```js
const fakeAsyncStuff = () => Promise.resolve();

const addOne = async n => {
  await fakeAsyncStuff();
  return n + 1;
};

const sum = async (a, b) => {
  await fakeAsyncStuff();
  return a + b;
};

const compute = async value => {
  const c = await addOne(value);
  const a = await sum(value, c);
  return c + a;
};

compute(1).then(console.log);
```